# Mail script needs running every hour, but cron not working

Tags: java, php, cron, sleep

Below is the fully functioning code. It works when I call it via the browser. However, I can't get my Cron job to run it. I have tried coming up with any solution and am open to any ideas that will make this script fire off once every hour 24/7 365 so to speak.

Info:

- Hostgator
- PHP 5.4
- Link for Hostgator Cron commands: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command?utm_source=cPanel&utm_medium=message&utm_campaign=Cron%20Jobs

I have tried the following:

When doing any of these I have yet to have it add a sale to the database or send a single email:

- `/opt/php54/bin/php /home1/user/public_html/Sales/scripts/sales-notif_em.php` - Could not open input file: /home1/user/public_html/scripts/sales-notif_em.php
- `php /home1/user/public_html/Sales/scripts/sales-notif_em.php` - blank email with nothing but this showing: Content-type: text/html
- `php -q /home1/lotscav1/public_html/Sales/scripts/sales_notif_em.php` - I don't get any emails from the system of course
- `/usr/bin/curl home1/user/public_html/scripts/sales-notif_em.php` - curl: (3)  malformed
- any command (like php or /usr/bin/curl) that has the second half with http://website.c0m/Sales/scripts/sales_notif_em.php - causes a JSON Error when trying to add the Cron job

I have checked the following things:

- File permissions are 655
- Timestamp is less than an hour old under the customers table

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//find out current time and 1 hour ago
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$current_time = strtotime("now");
$hour_ago = strtotime('-1 hour');

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////l// Connect to Sales Database  ///////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$mysqli_s = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", 
"server_sales_data");
if ($mysqli_s->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli_s->connect_errno . ") 
" . $mysqli_s->connect_error;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Connect to EM Database  ////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$mysqli_em = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", 
"server_dlgEM");
if ($mysqli_em->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL_EM: (" . $mysqli_em->connect_errno . 
") " . $mysqli_em->connect_error;
}

//Grab store name
$dlg_store = "EM";

$em_request = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE date BETWEEN '$hour_ago' 
AND '$current_time'";
$em_result = mysqli_query($mysqli_em, $em_request) or die("Error No 
Sales EM");
while ($em_row = mysqli_fetch_array($em_result)) {
$em_prod_num = $em_row["prod_num"];
$em_receipt = $em_row["receipt"];


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Grab info for EM Sales  ////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$request_s = "SELECT * FROM all_products WHERE 
dlgprod_num='$em_prod_num' AND dlg_store='$dlg_store'";
$result_s = mysqli_query($mysqli_s, $request_s) or die("Error dlg 
prod num EM");
while ($row_s = mysqli_fetch_array($result_s)) {
        $sku_s = $row_s["sku"];
        $dlgprod_num_s = $row_s["dlgprod_num"];
        $book_title_s = addslashes($row_s["book_title"]);
        $dlgprod_price_s = $row_s["dlgprod_price"];
        $author_name_s = addslashes($row_s["author_name"]);
        $author_email_s = $row_s["author_email"];
        $publisher_s = $row_s["publisher"];
        $dlg_store_s = $row_s["dlg_store"];

            $add_sql_s  = "INSERT INTO all_author_sales SET
            `sku`='$sku_s', 
            `dlgprod_num`='$dlgprod_num_s',
            `dlgprod_nam`='$book_title_s',
            `dlgprod_price`='$dlgprod_price_s',
            `author_name`='$author_name_s',
            `author_email`='$author_email_s',
            `publisher`='$publisher_s',
            `dlg_store`='$dlg_store_s',
            `dlgcustomer_receipt`='$em_receipt' ";  

//create signature
$sig = "The Admin Team at www.website.com";
//to
$admin_email = "admin@website.com";
$to = array($author_email_s, $admin_email);

//setup email headers
$headers='From: ' . $admin_email . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' . $admin_email . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= $emailbody."\n\n";

//email subject and body
$subject = "Your book stats";
$message = "
Hi $author_name_s,<br />
I just wanted to send you a message and let you know that the book or 
books below have just been purchased.<br /><br />

Store: $dlg_store_s<br />
Receipt: $em_receipt<br />
Sku Number: $sku_s<br /><br />

Book Title: $book_title_s<br />
Publisher: $publisher_s<br />
Product Number: $dlgprod_num_s<br />
Price: $dlgprod_price_s<br /><br />

Sincerely,<br />
$sig<br /><br />

To remove yourself from this notification, please send an email to 
$admin_email with Unsubscribe in the subject line.
";

            if ($mysqli_s->multi_query($add_sql_s) === TRUE) {
            mail (implode(',', $to), $subject, $message, $headers); 
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $add_sql_s . "<br>" . $mysqli_s-
>error . "<br>" . $string;
            }


    }



}


?>
```

Comment: Try working up to your full script in steps to see where the error lies. Start with a fresh file and simply log something, then do a query and log that...keep filling up the steps until it errors out and you'll know exactly what's causing it.

Comment: Thank you! Troubleshooting 101 lol. I always try to overcomplicate and forget the simple things first.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to try the Markdown formatting here, especially inline code formatting and unordered lists ("bullet points"), as it makes things much, much easier to read, and reduces volunteer editing work. Thanks. (At a guess, this may be the source of your downvotes).

Answer (score 0):

My bet is with wrong path to the php file you want to execute.

Try using terminal if you can, navigate to the folder where the file is placed and try running it from there via command line.

Also mind You are refering to two different names: sales-notif_em.php & sales-notif_me.php.

Comment: I am looking into the file path again. sorry about the two different files. I have 3 files one for each database. sales-notif_me, sales-notif_em, sales-notif_lc. It's just that em is the one I am testing with.

Comment: The path is correct because when it isn't it says file not found. I have sales as a sub-domain using the path Sale. I did redo the subdomain after changing the folder name to lowercase just to make it easier. I am making some changes to do trouble shooting so I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thank you for all your help. I made a custom product with my email as the author for testing purposes. In the customers table I inserted products 111111 and 111110. However, in all_products I gave products 11111111 and 11111110. tHE end result is I made a mistake.

I hope you are able to learn something from this event. Knowledge is more important than my ego. Thank you!